# Deleting splash screen gets strange error VS 2013

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2013, project-management

I had a project with a splash screen. It was giving me trouble so I removed my application framework. 
I.e. I did:

-Created a module to be the sub main

-In module create new() splash screen instance and main window instance to run application

-Went to project properties and disabled application framework

This worked without a problem. So I wanted to change my splash screen image, so I replaced the background image. When I did that I got this error:

"Two output file names resolved to the same output file path \obj\debug\.ACFSplashscreen.resources"

Which was weird. So I deleted that splash screen class, and decided to start clean. I *still* have that error. So I went into my file system and deleted that resources file. Now I have a new error saying it's unable to open it!

How can I find out what is looking for that file and fix it? Nothing in my code calls it anymore.

Comment: restore the resources file for starters - i'm sure you're using images/etc from it in other places of your project! if you go to your project, right click and go to properties - go to the resources tab and remove the troublesome image from there instead (should work-hopefully!)

Comment: I removed all images from the resources. I still have the errors. :(

Comment: clean your build and rebuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as to have an **"answer to your question"**;

Sometimes, if you delete a resource, it requires a simple **clean** of your project, followed by a **build**. This has been explained below: 
[From Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/5tdasz7h.aspx)

> delete any intermediate and output files. With only the project and
>   component files left, new instances of the intermediate and output
>   files can then be built.

Hence, allowing you to 'fix' your error.